Why is apollo not merging this response into the cache?
I have two queries which look like this:
const GetPayablesQuery = gql`
  query GetPayableInvoicesQuery(
    $paging: PagingGqlInputOfPayableInvoiceSortColumnGqlInput!
    $teamId: HashId!
    $filter: PayableInvoiceQueryFilterInput
  ) {
    team(teamId: $teamId) {
      payableInvoices(paging: $paging, filter: $filter) {
        items {
          ...PayableInvoiceFields
        }
        numPages
        pageNum
        pageSize
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
  ${PayableInvoiceFieldsFragment}
`;

const GetPayableQuery = gql`
  query GetPayableInvoiceQuery($payableInvoiceId: HashId!, $teamId: HashId!) {
    team(teamId: $teamId) {
      payableInvoice(payableInvoiceId: $payableInvoiceId) {
        ...PayableInvoiceFields
      }
    }
  }
  ${PayableInvoiceFieldsFragment}
`;

When I call the GetPayableQuery I thought it would merge the result into the cached items from the first query but it doesnt.
Fragment:
const PayableInvoiceFieldsFragment = gql`
  fragment PayableInvoiceFields on PayableInvoice {
    amount
    attachments {
      pageFiles
      url
    }
    canCancel
    canMarkAsPaid
    canPayNow
    canChangePaymentSource
    currency
    dueDate
    fundingSource {
      id
      mask
      name
      type
    }
    id
    invoiceNumber
    issueDate
    paymentDate
    paymentOptionRowVersion {
      value
    }
    rowVersion {
      value
    }
    status
    vendor {
      name
      email
      id
    }
  }
`;


What is the PayableInvoiceFields fragment?

"I thought it would merge the result into the cached items from the first query" - it will, if those have a known type and an id, but given both of your queries fetch the exact same fields I'm not quite sure what you'd expect such a "merge" to do?

Fragment added. I would expect the result of GetPayableQuery to be added to the cached items under teams > payableInvoices? Or am I misunderstanding

"I would expect the result of GetPayableQuery to be added to the cached items under teams > payableInvoices?" - yes, you seem to be misunderstanding that. The cache is only for sharing fields of the same entity (say, a team or an invoice) that were fetched through different queries. However, there is no relation between the payableInvoices(paging: …, filter: …).items list field and the payableInvoice(payableInvoiceId: …) field.

@Bergi Yes I see now that there is no relation between the two, what is the best way to create that relationship?

Well what do you want the relationship to be? You want all individually queried invoices to appear in the items list? If so, on what page, in which order, and how to apply the filter? Or do you want to resolve the individual field in the cache if the invoice has already been loaded as part of the list?

@Bergi Oh lawd, good points, refetchqueries it is

Also how are the payableInvoiceId and teamId parameters related to the PayableInvoice.id field (that Apollo will by use as the cache identifier by default)?
